# I have created a dropdown in Angular where there are values from 1 to 20 in it. If I select number <10 , it will show a msg and if >10 then diff. msg

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

html: -

```
   <div class="form-group">
              <label for="experience" class="form-label">I am experience</label>
                <select  class="custom-select" formControlName="experience" name="experience" onchange="change(this);">
                  <option *ngFor="let experience of experiences">{{experience}}</option>
                </select>
               
              </div>
```

ts:-

```
  experiencesLessThanTenYears = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  experiencesMoreThanTenYears = ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20'];
  experiences = [ ...this.experiencesLessThanTenYears, ...this.experiencesMoreThanTenYears];
```

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  startDate: [ '',[Validators.required]],
  endDate: ['',[Validators.required]],
  experience: ['',[Validators.required,]],
  })
```

I want to show message on selecting values less than 10 and greater than 10 on my view. Please help me on how to do that.

I tried using the change event of my html select but it was not working. I was hoping to make a custom validator but I don't know was just an idea. Please someone help me out

Comment: In .html: `({{+registrationForm.get('experience').value>10?'You have a great experience':'You have a poor experience'}}`. See the `+` before registrationForm, to convert to Number the input.

Comment: Great your solution worked.. But I want the message to be hidden when the page is loaded . I only want it to be shown when I am actually selecting any value.

Comment: I added a response :)

Comment: Really thank you. I learned a lot today :D @Eliseo

Comment: See that the `*ngIf="registrationForm.get('experience').value` work (I forgot indicate in the answer) because when you have a 0 experience is really a string "0" (when you use `*ngIf="condition"` it's true if "condition" different than null, 0, or '')

Comment: @Eliseo I have added one more question related to this project.. can you help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{+registrationForm.get('experience').value>10?
       'You have a great experience':
       'You have a poor experience'}}.
```

But this makes that if you don't selected anything show that you have a poor experience.

We can use a ng-container *ngIf in the way

```
<ng-container *ngIf="registrationForm.get('experience').value">
    {{+registrationForm.get('experience').value>10?
           'You have a great experience':
           'You have a poor experience'}}.
</ng-container>
```

Well, as we use a *ngIf, we can create a temporaly variable

```
<ng-container *ngIf="registrationForm.get('experience').value as experience">
    {{+experience>10?
           'You have a great experience':
           'You have a poor experience'}}.
</ng-container>
```

The another way is use a ternary operator inside a ternary operator. Really is an ugly (but equal effective solution)

```
{{registrationForm.get('experience').value?
       +registrationForm.get('experience').value>10?
            'You have a great experience':
            'You have a poor experience':
       ''}}
```